# Where is the workspace for tensorflow installed with anaconda?

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, bazel

I'm following the instruction [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/adding_an_op/index.html#with-tensorflow-binary-installation) to build user written op library. But my tensorflow is installed with anaconda. On a step I should run the following command in terminal:

```
$ bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/core/user_ops:zero_out.so
```

But I got:

```
The 'build' command is only supported from within a workspace.
```

Tensorflow was installed by cloning it from the repository. 
So where is the workspace??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to run `touch WORKSPACE` in the directory you are running the `build` command.

Bazel looks for an empty file named `WORKSPACE` in your workspace. You can also set the environment variable `$WORKSPACE` to another path if you don't want to use your current working directory.

There is a little more info here: https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/tutorial/workspace.html